# Как спроектировать систему react+django

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, проектирование

я разрабатываю домашний проект: сайт со стеком **django+react**, работать будет через api. На бекэнде у меня есть **функция, которая парсит некий контент с других сайтов** и этот процесс занимает время. Я хочу вызвать данный процесс с фронтенда и оповещать пользователя о процессе готовности, по типу: *осталось 30..29..28 секунд*, а после того, как функция на бэке закончит своё выполнение, она отдала ответ на фронт.

Обобщая всё, что я написал, я не могу понять, как сделать передачу оставшегося времени выполнения функции на фронт, а после передачи ответа.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам понадобятся [веб сокеты](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) скорее всего для непрерывного общения и [react-use-websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-websocket)

Но мне кажется можно поступить хитрее, если вам заранее известно сколько времни займёт весь процесс, то можно просто это число отправить на фронт, добавить дополнительно пару секунд для подстраховки и просто запустить самый обычный таймер отсчёта обратного времени

Comment: `если вам заранее известно сколько времни займёт весь процесс` мне кажется что это не возможно знать заранее. Слишком много факторов влияющих на скорость парсинга.  Ну а про веб сокеты соглашусь .

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Не буду спорить, сам не очень понял как автор это считает, но я отталкивался от `как сделать передачу оставшегося времени выполнения функции` и подумал, что он сам как-то приблизительно вычисляет это

Comment: Ну, счет времени я думаю сделать так: у нас есть n-ое число страниц, мы принимает одну страницу за некоторое число секунд, и при парсинге одной страницы получаем формулу `число страниц * секунды на 1 страницу - секунды на 1 страницу`. Это конечно самый недостоверный метод, но он же, на мой взгляд, самый простой

Comment: @Proksima Ну высчитывать приблизительное время можно по-разному. Методы передачи данных я вам подсказал :)

Comment: Ну да, понятно, что способов очень много. И все же, спасибо!